# Region of validity of classical statistical mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, estimation, approximations, semiclassical

Consider the argument (attached below) from Reif for the domain of validity of classical statistical mechanics, as applied to some fixed homogeneous substance. I am confused in particular with why the condition (7.4.2) is asserted as defining the region. In particular, he asserts that the system may be treated in terms of specifying a classical trajectory (with position and momentum each well-defined) if $\overline{R}\overline{p}>>\hbar$, where $\overline{R}$ is the mean separation between particles and $\overline{p}$ is their mean (in the sense described there in (7.4.6)) momentum.

What I do not follow is what (7.4.2) has to do with (7.4.1) (Heisenberg uncertainty) and with allowing us to define classical trajectories more generally. I am quite comfortable (c.f. Ashcroft and Mermin on semiclassical transport, and when the wavepacket notion allows us to simultaneously define momentum and position for a particle) with how we need to put constraints on the spread of the wavepacket which still respect (7.4.1) in order to define momentum and position for that particle, but why is that at all related to (7.4.2)? Indeed, (7.4.2) would seem to be a condition which is relevant for asserting whether interactions are strong or not (whether the ideal gas assumption is valid or not), despite the fact that Reif says an ideal gas may or may not respect (7.4.2). I am therefore clearly misunderstanding something, and am hoping that someone can explicate Reif's argument in more detail; in particular, explaining why (7.4.2) is the relevant condition for being able to define classical trajectories[image]. [image]

Comment: If the separation of particles is greater than their deBroglie length, then you are (approximatively/effectively) dealing with "point" particles: single particle wave functions do not overlap significantly, and QM interference & statistics (bose, fermi) are not so relevant.  Ofc the argument is heuristic, but it works in practical situations (when dealing with fluids).

Comment: @Quillo I agree that the nonoverlapping of wavefunctions leads us to be able to neglect indistinguishability, but here Reif seems to say we are making an argument for when we can treat the particles classically in terms of trajectory (which is quite apart from whether they are distinguishable or not, as he states in the very first sentence of the section).

Comment: @EE18 the first sentence is strange. What does he mean by "we saw that essential indistinguishability ... cannot be disregarded..."? If "the motion can be treated by classical mechanics" then I would say the particles are distinguishable.

Comment: @JánLalinský In the previous section he showed that we get the wrong expression for the entropy of an ideal gas (arising from not dividing the a priori classical partition function by $N!$) when we treat it classically. After making this adjustment, we are still treating it classically except for the indistinguishability of particles. At any rate, the current discussion (in this section) seems aimed at describing when classical trajectories make sense, does it not?

Comment: @EE18 ah that is a common misconception about ideal gas entropy, often given in textbooks. The Boltzmann entropy of ideal gas is not extensive, but that is easily fixed by defining $S_{standard~thermodynamics} = S_{Boltzmann}/N!$ or even $S_{Boltzmann}/N^N$ on the basis of requiring extensivity (which is a preference, not a physical law). No quantum magic is needed to explain this factor (divisor).

Comment: @EE18 I think the argument here is that let us imagine each particle as a wavepacket in physical space, what are some requirements on system parameters so that the wavepackets may be there without overlapping in physical space.

Comment: @JánLalinský I agree that that would do the trick in terms of allowing us to treat the particles as distinguishable, but I fail to see what that has to do with treating them as though they have classical trajectories.

Comment: The wavepacket (state that is almost classical)  argument is the physical picture here I think, practically what I was saying about non overlapping  1-particle states.

Comment: @EE18 if the wavepackets are isolated, their centers move as classical particles without interaction. However the wavepackets also spread out so this consideration with isolated wavepackets is defective, it is not clear why they should stay isolated.

Comment: @JánLalinský So your final assessment here is that Reif is making an argument about when interactions and/or quantum statistics matter, and has nothing to do with whether we can actually speak about them having well-defined (classical) position and momentum?

Comment: @EE18 I am not sure if I have a final assessment, but it seems to me that the argument is about the necessary conditions for the imagined wavepackets to be able to fit without overlapping. QT-based discussion of when the QT description is close to classical mechanics ideas on position, momentum and trajectories would be much more complicated.